# Automatically create a new variable containing different rows of information - using R studio

Tags: rstudio

I am currently generating a personality report for 170 managers. I am trying to display each manager's results in comparison to the entire population. Each manager's results is comprised of six dimensions. To display one manager's results, I change the data from wide format to long format, then I identify the managers's results (ex. rows 3, 23, 43, 63, 83, 103) and create a new variable called for the manager, labelled Henry. I then create a box plot for the entire population, and add Henry's results as a geom point

My question is: is there a way to automatically generate manager's results instead of having to manually create new variables (ex. Henry) and identifying the rows (3, 23, 43, 63, 83, 103)?

My code is as follows:

```
HEXACO<-data20[, c("Record","Emotionality","Extraversion", "Agreeableness", "Conscientiousness", "Openness", "Honesty_Humility")]

View(HEXACO)

data_long <- gather(HEXACO, Dimension, Score, Openness, Conscientiousness,Agreeableness,Extraversion, Emotionality, Honesty_Humility, factor_key=TRUE)

View(data_long)

Henry <-data_long[c(3, 23, 43, 63, 83, 103), c("Dimension", "Score")]

Manager_HEXACO <- ggplot(data = data_long, aes(x= Dimension, y= Score, fill=Dimension))+
    geom_boxplot(width = 0.6, alpha = 0.5) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")+
    coord_flip() + 
    theme_USGS_box()+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5))+
    expand_limits(y = 1:5)+
    geom_point(data = Henry,size = 2, color = "black")+
    labs(title = "HEXACO Profile")+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face="bold", margin = margin(10,10,10,10), family="serif"))+
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())+
    theme(axis.title.y=element_blank())+
    theme(legend.position = "none")

Manager_HEXACO
```

Comment: At this state it is difficult to help you without having a look at the `data20` object. Could you provide an example of this data.frame, like with `head(data20)` ?

Comment: yes of course. but it contains 144 variables - would you still like me to share that?

Comment: Here are a few examples of headings: JobSat_1 JobSat_R2 JobSat_3 JobSat_4 Ex_1 Ex_2 Ex_3 Ex_4 Ex_5 Ex_6 Ex_7 Ex_8 Ex_9 In_1 In_2 In_3 In_4 In_5 O_R1 C1 A1 X1 E1 H1 O1 C2 A_R1 X_R1 E2 H_R1 O2 C_R1 A_R2 X3 E3 H2 O_R2 C_R2 A_R3 X4 E4 H_R2 O3 C_R3 A2 X_R2 E5 H_R3 O_R3 C_R4 A3 X5 E_R1 H3 O4 C3 A4 X6 E_R2 H_R4 O5 C_R5 A5 X_R3 E6 H_R5 O_R4 C4 A6 X_R4 E_R3 H4 O_R5 C_R6 A_R4 X2 E_R4 H_R6 Com_X1 Com_X2 Com_C1 Com_A1 Com_O1 Com_E1 Com_E2R Com_H1R Com_H2R CS_1 CS_2 CS_3 CS_4 CS_5 CS_6 CS_7 CS_8 CS_9 OrgN_Y1 OrgN_Y2 OrgN_Y3 OrgN_Y4 OrgN_Y5 OrgN_Y6 OrgN_Y7 OrgN_Y8 OrgN_Y9 OrgN_X1 OrgN_X2 OrgN_X3

Comment: This is not easily readible in commentary. Could you edit your question and had a small example of you dataset? Like 5 columns (that I have understand to be managers) and the 6 rows.